# Simplify derivative expression

Tags: calculus

Trying to derive how

$$f(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{-cosx} + y\sin(x)e^{-cosx}$$

becomes

$$f(x) = (ye^{-cosx})'$$
Please kindly help.

Thank you

Comment: I think the derivation is just noticing that computing the derivative of your second equation yields the first equation?

Answer (score 0):

It's the product rule in reverse.  $d(uv) = u\,dv + v\,du$.  Therefore, the reverse is also true. $u\,dv + v\,du = d(uv)$.  In this case, $u = y$ and $v = e^{-\cos(x)}$.

Although, technically, I'm not sure you could call it $f(x)$ since it also has other terms, unless they knew the other terms were expressible in terms of $x$.